# Saving for loop output at particular range and update csv sheets

Tags: python-3.x

i have a data frame and i am running some code and getting some data as per data frame values  but data frame index count is 1.5 Million so it is taking time to extract the data and my server getting stop so whole process is stuck and again starting from zero.
I want to save extract the data in new csv file after every iteration or at after defined rows.

```
def get_dsm_coverage(df):
import math
import mpmath

list_2019 = []
list_2020 = []
list_2021 = []


for z in df.index:
    lat,long = (df['LATITUDE'][z],df['LONGITUDE'][z])
    print(z)
    
    zoom = 21
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat)
    lon_rad = math.radians(long)
    n=2**zoom
    xtile = str(int(n*((long+180)/360)))
    ytile = str(int(n*(1-(np.log(np.tan(lat_rad) +float(mpmath.sec(lat_rad))) / np.pi))/2))
    print(long,lat,xtile,ytile)
    
    for year in [2019,2020,2021]:
        url = 'https://api.gic.org/images/GetDSMTile/21/' +str(xtile)+ '/' +str(ytile)+'/?layer=bluesky-ultra&year='+str(year)
        r = requests.get(url, params= {'AuthToken':token})
        if r.status_code!=200:
            print('got inside')
            url = 'https://api.gic.org/images/GetDSMTile/21/' +str(xtile)+ '/' +str(ytile)+'/?layer=bluesky-ultra-g&year='+str(year)
            r = requests.get(url, params= {'AuthToken':token})
        try:
            content_type = r.headers['Content-type']
        except:
            content_type = 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1'
        
        if content_type == 'image/tiff':
            print(r.status_code)
            print(url)
            print(content_type)
            
            if year==2019:
                list_2019.append(1)
            elif year==2020:
                list_2020.append(1)
            else:
                list_2021.append(1)
                
        else:
            print(content_type)
            
            if year==2019:
                list_2019.append(0)
            elif year==2020:
                list_2020.append(0)
            else:
                list_2021.append(0)
        
return list_2019,list_2020,list_2021

list_2019,list_2020,list_2021 = get_dsm_coverage(df)
df['dsm_2019']=list_2019
df['dsm_2020']=list_2020
df['dsm_2021']=list_2021
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could provide a few example rows of your data if possible. That would make tinkering with a solution easier for us.

Comment: One thing to note, `print()` statements are very slow so you really want to limit them in a time sensitive loop.

Comment: i have two columns df[longitude] and df[latitude] by these two columns i am getting output (0, 1) in three list list_2019,list_2020,list_2021 than these list elements i want to update in input dataframe .1. df['dsm_2019'], df['dsm_2020'], df['dsm_20121] . After that that dataframe i want to save in excel or csv file but problem is ------->>>   input Index is 1.5M and before getting the complete output kernal interrupted and i lost  40,000 output values so i want to save output in csv file after every 40,000 iteration automatically.

Comment: i checked without print() statement but still taking too much time

Answer (score 0):

The crucial part is that we are going to keep track of calculations and regularly. Note this code does not actually hit the API and when run the first time it will intentionally error out so that you can restart it and see it recover. Note that the existence of the temp file signals that there is prior work and as such it should be cleaned up after a successful run.

```
import json
import math
import os
import random

import mpmath
import numpy
import pandas
import requests
import urllib3

#-------------------------------
# Don't build your own retry.
# Requests already supports it!
#-------------------------------
request_with_retry = requests.Session()
request_with_retry.mount("https://", requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(
    max_retries= urllib3.util.retry.Retry(
        total=5,
        backoff_factor=1,
        status_forcelist=[408, 409, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504]
    )
))
#-------------------------------

#-------------------------------
# We can pull this out of the main loop to simplify it
#-------------------------------
def get_tiles(latitude, longitude, zoom_level):
    lat_rad = math.radians(latitude)
    #lon_rad = math.radians(longitude)
    n = 2 ** zoom_level

    xtile = n * (longitude + 180) / 360
    ytile = n * (1- (numpy.log(numpy.tan(lat_rad) + float(mpmath.sec(lat_rad))) / numpy.pi)) / 2

    return int(xtile), int(ytile)
#-------------------------------

#-------------------------------
# Return a dictionary that contains prior saved work (or is blank)
# See: save_prior_work()
#-------------------------------
def fetch_prior_work(tmp_file_path):
    try:
        with open(tmp_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as temp_in:
            return json.load(temp_in)
    except (FileNotFoundError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
        return {}
#-------------------------------

#-------------------------------
# Save our work to a temp file.
# See: fetch_prior_work()
#-------------------------------
def save_prior_work(tmp_file_path, work_dictionary):
    with open(tmp_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as temp_out:
        json.dump(work_dictionary, temp_out)
#-------------------------------

def get_dsm_coverage(token, df, tmp_file_path):
    api_url_params = {'AuthToken': token}
    api_url_template = "https://api.gic.org/images/GetDSMTile/21/{xtile}/{ytile}/?layer=bluesky-ultra&year={year}"
    api_zoom_level = 21
    years = ["2019", "2020", "2021"]
    note_every = 3      # How often do we print
    save_every = 6      # How often do we save progress (probably every 100 or 1000)

    ## -------------------
    ## if our tmp_file_path exists, it represents prior work we can skip
    ## -------------------
    year_lists = fetch_prior_work(tmp_file_path)
    ## -------------------

    ## -------------------
    ## make sure our year_lists results is properly initialized
    ## -------------------
    for year in years:
        year_lists.setdefault(year, [])
    ## -------------------

    ## -------------------
    ## Determine if there is any prior work we can skip
    ## -------------------
    rows_already_processed = len(year_lists[years[0]])
    if rows_already_processed:
        print(f"skipping first {rows_already_processed} rows")
    ## ----------------------

    for z in df.index[rows_already_processed:]:
        ## ----------------------
        ## printing is expensive so let's only print every so often
        ## ----------------------
        if not z % note_every:
            print(f"Row: {z}")
        ## ----------------------

        ## ----------------------
        ## calculate the tile ids
        ## ----------------------
        xtile, ytile = get_tiles(df["LATITUDE"][z], df["LONGITUDE"][z], api_zoom_level)
        ## ----------------------
        
        for year in years:
            url = api_url_template.format_map({"xtile": xtile, "ytile": ytile, "year": year})

            ## ---------------------------
            ## TEST: We don't have a key....
            ## ---------------------------
            #response = request_with_retry.get(url, params=api_url_params)
            response = None
            ## ---------------------------

            try:
                content_type = response.headers['Content-type']
            except:
                content_type = "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"

            ## ---------------------------
            ## TEST: We don't have a key....
            ## ---------------------------
            content_type = random.choice(["image/tiff", content_type])
            ## ---------------------------

            if content_type == 'image/tiff':
                year_lists[year].append(1)
            else:
                year_lists[year].append(0)

        ## ----------------------
        ## Every so often, dump the work we have done to a temp file.
        ## ----------------------
        if z and not (z % save_every):
            print(f"\tSaving Temp File...")
            save_prior_work(tmp_file_path, year_lists)
        ## ----------------------

        ## ----------------------
        ## TEST: Force an error the first run so we can restart
        ## ----------------------
        if z == 10 and not rows_already_processed:
            raise Exception("Bummer")
        ## ----------------------

    return year_lists.values()

AUTH_TOKEN = ""
TMP_FILE_PATH = "./temp.json"

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    ("Ansonia", "CT", "USA", 41.346439, -73.084938),
    ("Walsenburg", "CO", "USA", 37.630322, -104.790543),
    ("Sterling", "CO", "USA", 40.626743, -103.217026),
    ("Steamboat Springs", "CO", "USA", 40.490429, -106.842384),
    ("Ouray", "CO", "USA", 38.025131, -107.675880),
    ("Leadville", "CO", "USA", 39.247478, -106.300194),
    ("Gunnison", "CO", "USA", 38.547871, -106.938622),
    ("Fort Morgan", "CO", "USA", 40.255306, -103.803062),
    ("Panama City", "FL", "USA", 30.193626, -85.683029),
    ("Miami Beach", "FL", "USA", 25.793449, -80.139198),
    ("Cripple Creek", "CO", "USA", 38.749077, -105.183060),
    ("Central City", "CO", "USA", 39.803318, -105.516830),
    ("Cañon City", "CO", "USA", 38.444931, -105.245720),
])
df.set_axis(["Name", "State", "Country", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"], axis=1, inplace=True)

list_2019, list_2020, list_2021 = get_dsm_coverage(AUTH_TOKEN, df, TMP_FILE_PATH)

## ----------------------
## if we get here, TMP_FILE_PATH should/could be deleted...
## ----------------------
try:
    os.remove(TMP_FILE_PATH)
except OSError:
    pass
## ----------------------

df['dsm_2019'] = list_2019
df['dsm_2020'] = list_2020
df['dsm_2021'] = list_2021

print(df)
```

One should expect the first execution to give:

```
Row: 0
Row: 3
Row: 6
        Saving Temp File...
Row: 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 167, in <module>
    list_2019, list_2020, list_2021 = get_dsm_coverage(AUTH_TOKEN, df, TMP_FILE_PATH)
  File "test.py", line 142, in get_dsm_coverage
    raise Exception("Bummer")
Exception: Bummer
```

and a following execution to give something like:

```
skipping first 7 rows
Row: 9
Row: 12
        Saving Temp File...
                 Name State Country   LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  dsm_2019  dsm_2020  dsm_2021
0             Ansonia    CT     USA  41.346439  -73.084938         0         1         1
1          Walsenburg    CO     USA  37.630322 -104.790543         1         0         0
2            Sterling    CO     USA  40.626743 -103.217026         0         1         0
3   Steamboat Springs    CO     USA  40.490429 -106.842384         0         0         0
4               Ouray    CO     USA  38.025131 -107.675880         0         0         0
5           Leadville    CO     USA  39.247478 -106.300194         1         0         1
6            Gunnison    CO     USA  38.547871 -106.938622         0         1         1
7         Fort Morgan    CO     USA  40.255306 -103.803062         1         0         0
8         Panama City    FL     USA  30.193626  -85.683029         0         1         1
9         Miami Beach    FL     USA  25.793449  -80.139198         0         1         1
10      Cripple Creek    CO     USA  38.749077 -105.183060         1         0         1
11       Central City    CO     USA  39.803318 -105.516830         0         0         0
12         Cañon City    CO     USA  38.444931 -105.245720         1         0         0
```